# Text not hiding on click

Tags: jquery, html

I have six boxes that each contain one paragraph each with different content. There is a character limit set to 200 characters. After 200 characters, the remaining content (if any) is hidden until the user clicks the `Show More` link.

When the user clicks the `Show Less` link the text show go back to the character limit. However, that is not the case; when the user clicks the `Show More` link all content is shown, but when the user clicks the `Show Less` link the content does not contract.

I saw other SO posts about show and hiding content, but after implementing their answers in effort to solve my issue, I am still lost. This is one of my first times implementing jQuery so please excuse my confusion at such an elementary level.

Any suggestions as to why the `Show Less` does not contract the content are appreciated.

```
<div class="col-md-8" id="article">
    <?php 
      $text = $page->Article_Text;
    ?>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
          var readMoreHTML = $(".read-more").html();
          var lessText = readMoreHTML.substr(0, 200);

          if(readMoreHTML.length > 200){
              $(".read-more").html(lessText).append("<a href=''class='read-more-link' style='color:gray; text-decoration:none'>Show More</a>");
          } else{
              $(".read-more").html(readMoreHTML);
          }
          $("body").on("click", ".read-more-link", function(event){
              event.preventDefault();
              $(this).parent(".read-more").html(readMoreHTML).append("<a href=''class='show-less-link' style='color:gray; text-decoration:none'>Show Less</a>");
          });
              $("body").on("click", ".show-less-link", function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent(".read-more").html(readMoreHTML.subtr(0,200)).append("<a href=''class='read-more-link' style='color:gray; text-decoration:none'>Show More</a>");
          });
      });
    </script>


    <div class="content">
       <div class="read-more">
           <?php echo $text ?>
        </div>
    </div>

</div><!--#article-->
```

(Please excuse the inline CSS as it is only for testing purposes).

Comment: First suggestion is to place your scripts just before your closing `</body>` tag. Second - put some space between your attributes (`href` and `class`).

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example (sans the php) and I (ore someone else) can help you with ease

Comment: Typo: `subtr` should be `substr`. Is that in the real code or a copying error?

Comment: @Barmar Thank you! I feel stupid

Comment: Unrelated note but `substr` is flagged as 'deprecated' on MDN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the last part of your JS, just use your `lessText` variable and it will work. The jQuery `.html()` method can't accept `readMoreHTML.subtr(0,200)` as an input.

```
$(this).parent(".read-more").html(lessText).append("<a href=''class='read-more-link' style='color:gray; text-decoration:none'>Show More</a>");
```

Working codepen:
http://codepen.io/staypuftman/pen/akZdzg

And also running code attached here. you can check output

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var readMoreHTML = $(".read-more").html();
        var lessText = readMoreHTML.substr(0, 200);

        if (readMoreHTML.length > 200) {
            $(".read-more").html(lessText).append("<a href=''class='read-more-link' style='color:gray; text-decoration:none'>Show More</a>");
        } else {
            $(".read-more").html(readMoreHTML);
        }
        $("body").on("click", ".read-more-link", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent(".read-more").html(readMoreHTML).append("<a href=''class='show-less-link' style='color:gray; text-decoration:none'>Show Less</a>");
        });
        $("body").on("click", ".show-less-link", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent(".read-more").html(lessText).append("<a href=''class='read-more-link' style='color:gray; text-decoration:none'>Show More</a>");
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="read-more">
    Details of G.M.’s decision-making process almost 20 years ago, which has not been reported previously, suggest that a quest for savings of just a few dollars per airbag compromised a critical safety device, resulting in passenger deaths. The findings also indicate that automakers played a far more active role in the prelude to the crisis: Rather than being the victims of Takata’s missteps, automakers pressed their suppliers to put cost before all else.
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It was technically a typo in `substr` which just replacing with the variable can solve or correcting the typo as well.

Comment: Good catch, I didn't even see that.